# MongoDB : reading the index instead of reading documents itself, reduce nscanned objects

Tags: mongodb, indexing, cursor, explain, compound-index

In the code below I am querying on the date and sorting by name (it can sound weird that I don't index the date field but I am doing that to avoid sorting in memory that's why I index by name).
If I am running an explain I got the following :

```
-> index on name
cursor: BtreeCursor name_1
scanAndOrder: False
nscanned: 1000
nscannedObjects: 1000
n:49
millis:1
```

Then if I create a compound index with the name and the date, I got the following output:

```
-> index on name + date
cursor: BtreeCursor name_1_date_1
scanAndOrder: False
nscanned: 1000
nscannedObjects: 1000
n:49
millis:1
```

Even if my query does not contain the index or its prefixes, to my mind the index should be able to read directly the date field from the index in the second case, therefore nscannedObject should be equal to n = 49. Indeed all information are already in the index and the number of scanned document should be equal to the number of returned results. It seems it is not the case here. Am I wrong or am I doing something wrong ?

```py
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient

import datetime 
import random

def printCursorExplain(e):
    print 'cursor: ' + e['cursor'] 
    print 'scanAndOrder: ' + str(e['scanAndOrder']) 
    print 'nscanned: ' + str(e['nscanned'])
    print 'nscannedObjects: ' +  str(e['nscannedObjects'])
    print 'n:' + str(e['n'])
    print 'millis:' + str(e['millis'])
    print '---------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n'

client = MongoClient()
db = client.DBQStackOverflow


name_list = ["Sylvain", "Tweety", "Toto", "Titi", "Sylvester"]
YEAR_LIST = [2014]

def generateRandomDate():

    YYYY = YEAR_LIST[random.randint(0,len(YEAR_LIST)-1)]
    MM   = random.randint(1,12)
    DD   = random.randint(1,28)
    date = datetime.datetime(YYYY, MM, DD) 
    return date

def insert():
    for i in range(0, 1000):
        start_date = generateRandomDate()        
        name = name_list[random.randint(0,len(name_list)-1)]
        db.collection.insert( {"date": start_date, "name" :name})


insert()

YYYY = 2014
MM   = 5
DD   = 1
dateCIS = datetime.datetime(YYYY, MM, DD) 


YYYY = 2014
MM   = 5
DD   = 12
dateCIE = datetime.datetime(YYYY, MM, DD) 


queryDict =  {"date" : {"$gte": dateCIS, "$lte": dateCIE}} 
db.collection.create_index([("name", pymongo.ASCENDING)])
db.collection.create_index([("name", pymongo.ASCENDING),("date", pymongo.ASCENDING)], pymongo.ASCENDING)

print "-> index on name"
cursor1 = db.collection.find(queryDict).hint([("name", pymongo.ASCENDING)]).sort([("name", pymongo.ASCENDING)])#.limit(100)
e1 = cursor1.explain()
printCursorExplain(e1)

print "-> index on name + date"
cursor2 = db.collection.find(queryDict).hint([("name", pymongo.ASCENDING),("date", pymongo.ASCENDING)]).sort([("name", pymongo.ASCENDING)])#.limit(100)
e2 = cursor2.explain()
printCursorExplain(e2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Both of your indexes result in a full scan of the index keys (`nscanned`) and documents (`nscannedObjects`) for similar reasons.

> index on name

Since you are searching by `date` and sorting by `name`, this index can be used to return the results in correct sorted order .. but the `date` value requires comparison with every document to determine if the query matches.

> index on name + date

The `name` prefix still matches your sort order, but a compound index on `{name, date}` cannot be efficiently used to match on `date` values because all of the `name` values have to be inspected first. This is effectively the same outcome as the first index.

#### Recommended index

If you are querying on `date` and sorting by `name`, the optimal index order should actually be `{date, name}`. This will make the index useful for both matching the `date` values *and* returning results in sorted order by `name`.

Note: in general you do not want to use the `hint()` command to force a specific index to be used (although I presume you're doing it in this case to test outcomes). If the query optimiser is not choosing the index you expect, it is likely that the index isn't the best choice.

You should find this blog post a helpful read: [Optimizing MongoDB Compound Indexes](http://emptysqua.re/blog/optimizing-mongodb-compound-indexes/).

Comment: Hi, thx. I was actually doing this test after reading the article you mentionned :).

Comment: Actually the author says : "So I've solved the scanAndOrder problem, at the cost of a higher nscanned. I can't reduce nscanned, but can I reduce nscannedObjects?" and the answer is yes. Indeed nscanned can not be reduced due to key orders in index. However nscanned object should be reduced as the author explains. Indeed why read the document whereas you can read the value directly from the index ? But what sounds strange is that my experience does not reproduce the expected behavior...Thus there is something weird somewhere ...

Answer (score 0):

The point is that MongoDB cannot use either of your indexes to determine which documents match the query criteria. It can use either index to help with the sort. So MongoDB scans the whole index because this will return the documents in the correct order, but still needs to pull up each document (nScannedObjects = 1000) to check if it matches the query criteria.

Comment: Thx, I agree this can not reduce nscanned but should reduce nscqnnedObject (to my mind), as I try to explain below